# How to create a test pipeline in Gitlab CI for a Docker based PHP App

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, gitlab-ci

Up until now I had/have a healthy working pipeline on Gitlab CI with two stages (build & deploy).

Now I want to add a test stage between these two and I want to run the tests on the image built in the previous stage. How should I proceed?

Right now with this CI file I will get a running container and a web server starts listening and nothing & it stays indefinitely, which I don't want.

```
variables:
    CONTAINER_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/XXXXXXXXX:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    CONTAINER_IMAGE_HASHED: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/XXXXXXXXX:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

build:
    stage: build
    before_script:
        - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    script:
        - echo "Start building XXXXXXXXX container"
        - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
        - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
        - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
        - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    environment:
        name: staging
        url: $PUBLIC_ADDRESS

test:
    stage: test
    image: docker:stable
    services:
        - docker:dind
    script:
        - docker run --rm $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE /bin/bash -c "vendor/bin/phpunit"
    environment:
        name: test

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - echo -e "$KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - chmod 600  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    script:
        - apk update && apk add openssh-client
        - ssh $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY &&
          docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE &&
          docker stop XXXXXXXXX || true &&
          docker rm XXXXXXXXX || true &&
          docker run -d -p 80:80 --name XXXXXXXXX $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    environment:
        name: production
        url: $PUBLIC_ADDRESS
```

I want to run tests(including PHPUnit) and on failure or success the container should be closed and removed (--rm) and proceed to deploy (lets say on success) (with allow_failure: true/false).

Edit 1:

This way also gives the same result (container running and stays running):

```
...
test:
    stage: test
    image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    services:
        - docker:dind
    before_script:
        - cd webroot
        - composer install
        - composer run-script post-root-package-install
    script:
        - vendor/bin/phpunit
    environment:
        name: test
...
```

Comment: Please check your question title. It is an open-ending asking (the topic is _very_ broad). What is your concrete problem and what prevents you to turn it into a concrete question (and not a description what you generally want to do and then run into some problem - we all do every day, Stackoverflow works best for concrete questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up your build job with the combination of an `after_script` section and the new `CI_JOB_STATUS` variable, which is predefined by Gitlab CI/CD and passed to `after_script` automatically as long as you're running Gitlab version 13.5 or higher, or use Gitlab.com.

```yaml
...
test:
    stage: test
    image: docker:stable
    services:
        - docker:dind
    script:
        - docker run --rm $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE /bin/bash -c "vendor/bin/phpunit"
    after_script:
      - if [ $CI_JOB_STATUS == "failed" ]; then ./cleanup_image.sh; fi
    environment:
        name: test
...
```

Where `cleanup_image.sh` represents the steps you'd do to remove the image.

You can review the available variables [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)